# Consuming REST API using razor MVC .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, razor

I'm creating rest api MVC, to make model i'm using entity framework and to make my controller i'm using scaffolding item, i have my views(razor) but i dont know how to get data o how to post data from my view to my controller.

Somebody help me please!

**Model**

```
public partial class Information
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
private BaseNegociosEntities db = new BaseNegociosEntities();

// GET api/Informacion
public IEnumerable<Information> GetInformations()   
{
    return db.Information.AsEnumerable();


public HttpResponseMessage PostInformacion(Informacion informacion)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Informacion.Add(informacion);
        db.SaveChanges();

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, information);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = information.Id_Informacion }));
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your view(s)?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create list in model.

```
           List<Information> list1=new List<Information>{get;set;}
```

Then need to feed data into that list from controller. So you can send your Model's list to view. Then you can serialize your list to xml or json.